# Calculate inverse of dense matrix with entries of very different magnitude

Tags: linear-algebra, stability, inverse

I need to calculate the inverse of a dense matrix, with some elements taking values as high as 1e9 and some around 1e2. What would be the best method to do it?

**Note:**

- I am more concerned about the **precision** of the answer rather than minimizing the computational time.
- I explicitly need to find the `inverse` and not the solution of any linear system `Au=b`.

**Size:** The size of the matrix is below $100 \times 100$.

**Formula** The formula for Pade Approximation of order 3,3 can be given as:

$\left(120I_{n\times n}+60A+12A^2+A^3\right)\times\left(120I_{n\times n}-60A+12A^2-A^3\right)^{-1}$

where,

`A` is the matrix whose exponential is to be found out.

This is the Pade Approximation for order 3,3. I am trying to implement a Pade approximation of order 13,13 in which the coefficient of $I_{n\times n} \text{is}$ `17643225600`

**Implementation:** I am implementing the Pade Approximation for finding the exponential of a matrix in which I need to find the inverse of the "denominator" matrix.

Comment: @ChristianClason Thanks, I have edited the question. I hope that makes it more relevant and catchty.

Comment: @ChristianClason I  tried my best, hope that clears it.

Comment: @ChristianClason I know, its kind of worthless to find out the inverse of the matrix. But the above problem is my term project and I have to go ahead with it.

Comment: No worries, it's just important to be as explicit as possible about any side conditions so you can get the answer need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the condition number of the matrix $A$, computing Padé approximations of the matrix exponential $e^A$ is horribly ill-conditioned, especially for such high orders. If a problem is ill-conditioned, no amount of mathematical trickery will allow a stable computation; however, often you can change the problem to one that is better conditioned (and still leads to the desired result). What to do depends on the precise nature of your assignment:

- If the goal is an approximation of the matrix exponential, look at one of the better ways in Clive Moler and Charles van Loan's seminal paper [Nineteen dubious ways to compute the exponential of a matrix](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/19ways+.pdf), SIAM Rev., 45(1), 3–49. (In particular, #2 on page 10ff discusses Padé approximations, and you should consider the scaling and squaring method #3.)
- If it has to be a Padé approximation, there are more robust ways to computing it via SVDs instead of direct inversion; see, e.g. Pedro Gonnet, Stefan Güttel, and Lloyd N Trefethen's paper [Robust Padé approximation via SVD](http://www.guettel.com/download/gonnet_guettel_trefethen.pdf), SIAM Rev., 55(1), 101–117. (This paper deals with Padé approximation of real functions, not matrix functions, so some further work is required.)
- Otherwise, for the matrix size and type you are looking at, and since you don't care so much about performance, I don't see a better way than using a direct solver (e.g., LU decomposition) from a  high-quality library to solve 
  for each unit vector $e_i$, $i=1,\dots N$ the linear system $B m_i = e_i$ and set $M=[m_1,\dots,m_N]$. Depending on the software framework, you should use the highest precision data type available to minimize round-off errors.

Comment: Regarding the _3rd point_ is it better to use **Gauss-Jordan** Method or solve the **Gauss Elimination** with pivoting `n-times`.

Comment: Mathematically, all methods implemented by direct solvers are equivalent to Gauss elimination with pivoting (possibly exploiting the structure of the matrix to reduce effort). Since you are dealing with such a difficult problem, you really should not implement your own method and rather use a library written by experts (which are tuned down to the specific machine-language instructions to give the best possible stability).